# Is there a way for the iPad wireless keyboard to make typing sounds similar to what the on-screen keyboard makes?

Tags: audio, keyboard, ipad

Is there a way to have a wireless keyboard produce the soft tapping sound effects that the on-screen iPad keyboard makes?

The point is that I want to be able to type and not look at the screen at all for a long period of time. Can’t do that with the touch screen, I just want to be audibly certain that that what I am typing on the physical keyboard is actually going into the document.

I can’t think when I’m staring into the screen, and it hurts my eyes after a while. It’s purely for creative writing purposes. My Googling suggests that not many people are looking for this kind of thing and apps/software for the blind overshoot the point. I just want the tapping noises.